# How do you connect to wifi in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: networking, wireless

When I click on the internet button, it doesn't give me the option to connect to a WiFi network or search for one. I have tried multiple different techniques to get it to work and it doesn't connect.

Can you please give some advice on how to connect?

Comment: top right corner.. did you see by clicking it aand the menu? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiRWA.jpg

Comment: What "Internet button" ? What DE are you using - gnome ?

Comment: no i didn't see it in the menu, i saw the network connections, but the wifi was not there

Comment: then it seems wifi driver/ adapter problem..